# How to correctly write grandparent rule

Tags: prolog

This is my first homework assignment using prolog, I thought I knew what I was doing but when I write a query it says 
"procedure `parent(A,B)' does not exist
Reachable from:
      grandparent(A,B)".

```
female(jane).
female(mary).
female(clare).
female(vivian).
female(alice).
female(sarah).
female(rachel).

male(floyd).
male(tom).
male(richard).
male(calvin).
male(john).
male(andrew).

parent_of(tom, richard).
parent_of(tom, jane).
parent_of(mary, calvin).
parent_of(mary, alice).
parent_of(clare, john).
parent_of(clare, tom).
parent_of(john, alice).
parent_of(john, calvin).
parent_of(richard, vivian).
parent_of(richard, floyd).
parent_of(jane, sarah).
parent_of(jane, rachel).
parent_of(jane, andrew).

grandparent(X,Z):-parent(X,Y),parent(Y,Z).
sister_of(X,Y):-parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y),female(X),X\==Y.
brother_of(X, Y):-parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y),male(X),X\==Y.
```

Comment: It is `parent_of/2`, not `parent/2`.

Comment: Are you trying this in SWISH (https://swish.swi-prolog.org/) and hovering with the mouse over the highlighted code? Immediate feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your predicates as

```
parent_of/2
```

Look at your code again

```
parent_of(tom, richard).
parent_of(tom, jane).
parent_of(mary, calvin).
parent_of(mary, alice).
parent_of(clare, john).
parent_of(clare, tom).
[...]
```

therefore you also have to use parent_of in your grandparent predicate like following:

```
grandparent(X,Z):-parent_of(X,Y),parent_of(Y,Z).
```

please note, that you have to change the following predicates aswell (sister_of and brother_of):

```
sister_of(X,Y):-parent_of(Z,X),parent_of(Z,Y),female(X),X\==Y.
brother_of(X, Y):-parent_of(Z,X),parent_of(Z,Y),male(X),X\==Y.
```